# Django Form with related data from two other tables displayed using a nested (optgroup) <select>

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying to duplicate the functionality of this manually created `<select>` using a proper Django form.

```
{% regroup roll_counts by get_type_display as roll_list %}
<select name="film">
    <option>Select a film</option>
    {% for type in roll_list %}
    <optgroup label="{{ type.grouper }}">
        {% for film in type.list %}
        <option value="{{film.id}}">{{ film.manufacturer }} {{ film.name }} ({{ film.count }})</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </optgroup>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

The queryset for `roll_counts` looks like this:

```
roll_counts = Film.objects\
    .filter(roll__owner=owner, roll__status='storage')\
    .filter(format=camera.format)\
    .annotate(count=Count('name'))\
    .order_by('type')
```

I'm trying to recreate this using some sort of Django `ModelForm` to be able to actually validate data submitted to the form. The ultimate goal is to be able to "load" a camera with a roll of film. Which is to say: associate a `Roll` (with a foreign key to `Film`) with a particular `Camera` and mark said camera with a status of `loaded`. So the `<select>` displays data that isn't being updated by the form. What needs to be modified are the `Roll` and `Camera` models, not the `Film` model. But I assumed all that could be handled within the view that receives data from the form.

I'm unsure how to get a `ModelForm` to display the aforementioned `roll_count` query (and nested/`optgroup` `<select>`) since it doesn't relate to a single field on that `Film` model.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

---

**Update:**

The accepted answer got the nesting part of the puzzle solved, but another part of it was getting the data passed from the view into the form and the QuerySet for the field working.

In the view, you can pass whatever you want to a form instance:

```
form = LoadCameraForm(owner=owner, format=camera.format)
```

In the form, I added a custom `__init__` (note the `owner, format` between `*args` and `**kwargs`):

```
def __init__(self, *args, owner, format, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['roll_counts'].queryset = Film.objects\
        .filter(roll__owner=owner, roll__status='storage')\
        .filter(format=format)\
        .annotate(count=Count('name'))\
        .order_by('type')
```

(I'm still unsure how to get my annotated `count` to show up yet.)

Then to put all the pieces together, the field entry in the form looks like this:

```
roll_counts = GroupedModelChoiceField(\
    label='Pick a film to load',\
    queryset=None,\
    group_by_field='type')
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10573/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did that once! See my snippet here :) https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10573/

Comment: How would you go about getting at the "display" text of a choice field if that were the field you were grouping by?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in form field that can do what you want, so you will have to create your own custom field and a widget for rendering the field to HTML. Take a look at django.forms.fields module and you will see how the form fields are defined. Though for some, it may be a challenge to get it right.

To be honest, i would recommend to search for another option for displaying your form. You could have a select field for `type` and when selected, you can load the options for `film` using ajax?

Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: Cool, thanks! The reason I want `type` built into this is that this form is displayed on a page where the user has already selected a camera and it will only show film that's compatible with that camera.